# Passing the value of a select from view to controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have form which has one select box and i need to pass select box selected value to laravel resources `show()` method for display specific details of selected value.

```
<form action="{{ action('supplierController@show') }}" method="POST" class="form" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" control-label">company name</label>
      <select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" name="seller">
        <option value=""></option>
        @foreach($supplierlist as $supplier)
          <option value="{{ $supplier->company_name }}">{{ $supplier->company_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">GO</button>
</form>
```

Values of selectbox come from database so how can i pass value of selected value of selectbox to my controller.

Comment: Please stop changing the original question, as the answers and discussions will make no sense then.

Comment: Show your controller function (`supplierController@show`)

Answer (score 2):

The `<select>` should have a name, then you can get the value with `request()->get('name')`.

Comment: can i directrly pass value of specific selected value??

Comment: When you use `request()->get('name')`,  the selected `<option>`'s value will be passed to the Controller.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it pass value `http://localhost:8000/supplier?suppliername=sheetal` instead of `http://localhost:8000/supplier/show/sheetal`

Comment: That's how it works. After submit, you could do a redirect to the correct url.

Comment: can you explain me in brief??

Comment: `return redirect()->to(action('supplierController@show'), request()->get('name'))` is a possible solution.

Comment: You should run it in your Controller, in the function defined in the `<form action>`. Then in that method, you should return a redirect to the actual showing method, with the code I use. It's pretty hard for me to actually fix your issue, without having the code in front of me, so I suggest you try yourself with the advicements I've given you.

Comment: here your code be like this request->get('seller');

Comment: But i is not redirect on any method where i put `return redirect()->to(action('supplierController@show'), request()->get('name'))` inside my method, and if you sugest me i will share my code with you.

Comment: should you pass Request parameter in ur method?

Answer (score 0):

> Please try the following 
>   In your view part include the following consider the $categories contains the category to be in the options

{!! Form::select('category', array('0' => 'Choose Category') + $categories , ['class' => 'medium m-wrap']) !!}

> In your controller include

```
$category = $request->get('category');
```