# Laravel - Controller get select value from Views

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a bulletin board using Laravel, and I want the articles on the board can shown by selecting the years (ex. when choosing 2022, only show the articles post in 2022). I refer to many similar questions and Laravel's offical website but not went well, there is what I got right now:

select in ' blade.php ' :

```
<select name="article_year" onchange="">
    @foreach ($year as $item)
        <option value="{{ $item->id}}">{{ $item->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

index() in 'Controller.php' :

```
$article_year = $request->get('article_year');
$data['news'] = (new Article())->where('user_year', $article_year)->get();
```

Can any one tell me what the problem is? Thanks!

Some website I refer to:

[Laravel - HTTP Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#main-content)

[Laravel Discuss - How to get value from Select box](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-get-value-from-select-box)

[Passing the value of a select from view to controller in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854981/passing-the-value-of-a-select-from-view-to-controller-in-laravel)

full code of Controller

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use App\Catalog;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Request;
use App;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(){}

    public function index()
    {
        $locale = Request::segment(1);
        $view = 'home';
        $article_year = $request->get('article_year');

        $data['year'] = (new Catalog())->where('catalog_type_id', 3)->where('is_active', 1)->orderBy('sort_num', 'asc')->get();
        $data['news_pin'] = (new Article())->where('is_active', 1)->where('user_year', $article_year)->orderBy('sort_num', 'desc')->get();
        $data['news'] = (new Article())->where('is_active', 0)->where('user_year', $article_year)->orderBy('sort_num', 'desc')->get();       

        return view($view, $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more? what does your query return now? and what's the problem?

Comment: Hello there, did you try to check the value of $article_year variable ? Or if $article_year is set, do you check what variable $data has ?

Comment: why not using 'Article::where('user_year', $article_year)->get();' instead of '(new Article())->where('user_year', $article_year)->get();'

Comment: I tried using 'Article::where('user_year', $article_year)->get();' but still not working.

Comment: The problem is the website keep showing Server Error(500) when I try to get the data from select and send back the data. (Everything worked fine before I add this function, so I didn't post all code. I will put them under my original post, I think it can be more clear.) Thank you everyone for answering my question.

Comment: I can't get your questions properly can you explain more about what is the problem are facing now

Comment: Please never edit your question to mark it as `solved`. Accepting an answer is how a page is marked as resolved.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I will remeber next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have missed some depencies to pass on index method.... That the reason you getting 500 server error

In your index method you have not passing the $request variable..i think the code should be like this

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $locale = Request::segment(1);
        $view = 'home';
        $article_year = $request->get('article_year');

        $data['year'] = (new Catalog())->where('catalog_type_id', 3)->where('is_active', 1)->orderBy('sort_num', 'asc')->get();
        $data['news_pin'] = (new Article())->where('is_active', 1)->where('user_year', $article_year)->orderBy('sort_num', 'desc')->get();
        $data['news'] = (new Article())->where('is_active', 0)->where('user_year', $article_year)->orderBy('sort_num', 'desc')->get();       

        return view($view, $data);
    }
```

And also add this line on top of the conrtoller file

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and added a submit button then it works as I wanted.

Comment: have a great day ...but next time while asking question be clear about ..what is the exact error you where getting which will helps others to debug it quickly & more efficiently

Comment: Ok. It's my first time asking question, I will make a progress next time. Wish you have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all answering, every one give me the different thought and help me found the answer. There is my code which is working:

---

route-web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

blade.php

```
<form>
    <select name="article_year">
        @foreach ($year as $item)
            <option value="{{ $item->name}}">{{ $item->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
    </form>
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use App\Catalog;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $view = 'home';
        $value = $request->article_year;

        $data['year'] = (new Catalog())->where('catalog_type_id', 3)->where('is_active', 1)->orderBy('sort_num', 'asc')->get();
        $data['news_pin'] = (new Article())->where('is_active', 1)->where('user_year', $value)->orderBy('sort_num', 'desc')->get();
        $data['news'] = (new Article())->where('is_active', 0)->where('user_year', $value)->orderBy('sort_num', 'desc')->get();

        return view($view, $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$article_year = $request->get('article_year');
$data['news'] = Article::where('user_year', $article_year)->get();

return $data;
```

Comment: I tried using 'Article::where('user_year', $article_year)->get();' but still not working.

Comment: Which type of error you are getting ?

Comment: I found the problems and fixed it. Thanks! I think the problems is I the value didn't post properly, so I keep getting Server Error(500).